# Expected behavior of 555 timer in monostable mode

Tags: timer, 555, monostable

While assembling the 555 timer based circuit below I noticed that 1) the intended delay on pin 3 only works if the switch on pin 2 is closed before attaching the circuit to the 9V power supply.

[image]
Source: [circuitdigest](https://circuitdigest.com/electronic-circuits/1-minute-timer-circuit)

2) If the power supply is already attached and pin 2 is opened, closing it will produce the desired turn on delay on pin 3, which is fine.

My first question is whether scenario #1 is indeed the expected behavior in monostable mode (or perhaps a flawed construction on my part). The second question is whether it is possible to provide a delay also in the case where pin 2 remained closed but the power supply would be removed and reattached later on.

PS: I have looked into [a similar question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318656/555-timer-in-monostable-mode-with-reset-on-the-same-momentary-button) but was not convinced it can help in this case.

Comment: That schematics is incorrect.  For a start R1 is connected to the wrong side of the switch.  There is also no current limiting resistor with the LED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the switch pressed, the TR input is open, hence undefined. With an undefined input, you can't expect any specific behaviour.

Maybe you intended R1 to be a pull-up? As drawn, it has no function.

What voltage do you expect on pin 6 when you apply power? As drawn, it is undefined. A diode could be added to discharge C1 to the power rail.

And as HandyHowie remarks, the LED needs a current-limiting resistor.

Comment: Thank you for your input Wouter! For TR, I was thinking as a next step to attach a 1n4148 diode to GND to prevent the undefined state. However, I am not 100% sure how I would discharge C1 via a diode across the power rail. Can you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: The idea is: when power is removed, the circuitry will still try to draw some power, so it will draw the power rail doen to ~ ground (0V) level. Hence a diode *to* power will discharge your C when power is removed.

Comment: Fantastic, I will try it out when I am back home this evening! Thank you!

Comment: Well, sthat was only for a start... did you consider what will happen when you trim RV1 to 0 Ohm and the DC pin tries to discharge the C?

Comment: IIRC there is a monostable circuit in the 555 datasheet. Why not use that??

Comment: I ended up using [this](http://555-timer-circuits.uk/operation/delay-on.gif) schematic with the only difference that pin 3 is connected to the positive end of the LED and the other end connected to GND. That way the circuit powers the LED only after a delay t based on the values of R1 and C1.